# 'getLocalizableSampleTemplate' does not display as expected with Xcode 15.2

Tags: swiftui, apple-watch-complication

When I use Xcode15 create complications with Apple Watch, `getLocalizableSampleTemplate` not display as expected, how to fix this error?

Expect the code to show the actual effect (without using the WidgetKit framework)

```
    func getLocalizableSampleTemplate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTemplate?) -> Void) {
        if complication.family == .graphicCircular {
            let template = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCircularView(
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            )
            handler(template)
        } else {
            let template = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicRectangularFullView(
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            )
            handler(template)
        }
    }
```

[image: screenshot]